# Absolute value of difference of squares

Tags: calculus, absolute-value

I am working through the Stewart Calculus text independently and am stuck on one of the practice problems (edition 7e - problem 29 in section 1.7).

I am confused by particularly by hint #3 which says:

Why is $\lvert x^2 -4x + 4 \rvert = \lvert x + 2 \rvert \lvert x - 2 \rvert$

I am quite confused by this and I cannot figure out how these two sides of the equation are equal. For full context of the homework hints please see [here](https://www.stewartcalculus.com/media/10_inside_homework_hints.php?show_cat=2&book=7e&hint_id=h00570) (I would have attached the image but I cannot since I have not posted enough).

Left to my own device I would have figured that $\lvert x^2 -4x + 4\rvert \lt  \epsilon $ where the left hand sides could be reworked as $ \lvert  (x -2)^2 \rvert \lt \epsilon $ and furthermore that $ x - 2 = \sqrt{\epsilon}$

Not sure where I am going wrong here, can somebody please help?

Comment: Is there a typo in the last term?

Comment: I am sorry for my incompetence but what do you mean by type? I am dealing with all real numbers if that is what you are asking..

Comment: yes, typo indeed. fixed

Comment: $|x^2-4x+4|$ does not equal $|x+2||x-2|$, e.g., when $x=-2$ or $x=4$

Answer (score 2):

**Solution**

Suppose that $|x - 2| \leq \delta$. Then one has that
\begin{align*}
|f(x) - f(2)| & = |x^{2} - 4x + 5 - 1|\\\\
& = |x^{2} - 4x + 4|\\\\
& = |x-2|^{2} \leq \delta^{2} = \varepsilon 
\end{align*}

Thus we can conclude that for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there corresponds $\delta = \sqrt{\varepsilon}$ such that
\begin{align*}
|x - 2| \leq \delta \Rightarrow |f(x) - f(2)| \leq \varepsilon
\end{align*}

and we are done.

If you still have any doubts, please let me know.

**Comments**

The proposed identity is not correct. Indeed, $|x^{2} - 4x + 4| \neq |x-2||x+2|$.

Comment: excellent, thank you! This is the solution I came up with as well but was deeply confused by the homework hints - but now I suspect that these hints are maybe not for the right problem.

Just saw your comment, thanks for the additional comment, thought I was losing my head there for a second.

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your question, I think there was a typo in that hint #3; that should be $$|x^2-4x+4| = |x\color{red}-2||x-2|$$ instead.